# Selenium IDE upload <input name=imgfile> directly from hard drive

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm working on dealing with an image-chooser dialog using Selenium - IDE.

The problem is getting Selenium to properly click on the "Choose File" button. Since the original source html is simply , the browser determines how to render it as a field and a button. 
This works by using the following in the GUI :

```
Command: type
Target: //input[@name='imgfile']
Value: C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg
```

When I execute this command alone this works (sometimes, it doesn't work as well, n't figure out when it works and when it doesn't). 
But from the moment i'm trying to run the full test case he executes the command but nothing happens.. Also there is no error.

[info] Executing: |type | //input[@name="imgfile"] | C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg |

What am I doing wrong ?

Btw, what should I change to tell the command that he can only select the first child with @name='imgfile' ?

This is the html code :

```
<input type="file" name="imgfile" multiple="" accept="image/*" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer;">
```

Video of the problem : 
https://vid.me/Wtxx

*Edit*
Tried it on another site that uses forms and there it works without a problem

Html of the working uploader on site X:

```
<div class="qq-upload-button" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">    
<div>Foto's toevoegen</div>

<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; height: 105px; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;"></div>
```

Html not working form on site Y:

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 0; direction: ltr; z-index: 2147483583; left: 178px; top: 529px; width: 129px; height: 129px; visibility: hidden;">
<input style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" accept="image/*" multiple="" name="imgfile" type="file"></div>
```

Comment: Try replacing \ with \\

Comment: Stackoverflow ignored the double \\ so i am actually using them in selenium